# Is there a way to automatically expose properties and events of a standard wpf control wrapped in a user control?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I wrapped a standard control as discussed here [Quickest way to inherit a standard control in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773387/quickest-way-to-inherit-a-standard-control-in-wpf)

in a user control. Now is there a way to automatically expose properties and events of a standard wpf control wrapped in a user control ? Could I use something like automatic Bubbling routing but how exactly ?

Otherwise I'll have to also create properties and events wrappers for my component that is cumbersome.

Comment: The answer to the question that you linked to explains the issues involved pretty well.  If you want your control to expose the properties and events of a standard WPF control, make it a custom control, not a user control.  User controls only have the properties and events that you explicitly implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to provide new Dependency Properties on the user control to expose properties to the outside. As an example:

TimeframeSelector.xaml

```
<DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Path=StartDate, 
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                              AncestorType={x:Type ctrl:TimeframeSelector}}}"/>
```

TimeframeSelector.xaml.cs

```
    public DateTime StartDate
    {
        get{ return (DateTime)GetValue(StartDateProperty);}
        set { SetValue(StartDateProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty StartDateProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "StartDate", 
        typeof(DateTime), 
        typeof(TimeframeSelector), 
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
            DateTime.MinValue,
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
```

You need to use the `RelativeSource` binding as you won't find the DP in the visual tree otherwise. If you are using Visual Studio, there is template named `propdp` which you can use to create depedendency properties very fast.